# Does $WKL_0$ provide more comprehension than $RCA_0$?

Tags: lo.logic, reverse-math

$WKL_0$ extends $RCA_0$ with the statement that any infinite subset of the infinite binary tree has an infinite branch. Does $WKL_0$ Prove that there are sets which are not proven to exist by the $\Delta_0$-comprehension schema of $RCA_0$? If so, to what level of comprehension do such sets belong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is 
"no" in the following sense:

Fix a model $M=(\omega_M, \mathbb{R}_M)$ of $RCA_0$, and let $\mathcal{C}_M$ be the set of structures $N=(\omega_N, \mathbb{R}_N)$ such that

- $N\models WKL_0$,
- $\omega_N=\omega_M$ (same first-order parts), and
- $\mathbb{R}_N\supseteq\mathbb{R}_M$ ($N$ is gotten by adding sets to $M$).

Then we have:

- $\mathcal{C}_M$ is nonempty. (This is due to Harrington, and is how he shows that $WKL_0$ is $\Pi^1_1$-conservative over $RCA_0$.)
- $\bigcap_{N\in\mathcal{C}_M} \mathbb{R}_N=\mathbb{R}_M$. That is, there is no *specific* set which must be added when we expand $M$ to a model of $WKL_0$. (This is a direct consequence of the proof of Jockusch and Soare's Low Basis Theorem, but I don't know who first explicitly observed this.)

In particular, the intersection of all the Scott sets is precisely $REC$, the set of recursive sets.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Note that my interpretation of your question here is not the same as my interpretation of your similar question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/220101/what-can-be-achieved-by-liberalizing-induction-for-rca-0 - I'm pretty sure this is what you mean in this question, but I don't know how to interpret your other question.

Comment: Is it true also for $WKL$ that adding induction does not add sets?

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by "does not add sets," but the argument at the end of my answer to your other question will still work with $WKL_0$ in place of $RCA_0$ - so I think the answer is "yes." In fact, I can't off the top of my head think of a reasonable theory over which that argument *won't* work, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In particular, may we assume that WKL with full induction does not prove the existence of the set of the Gödel numbers of formulas that it proves?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Yes, that is true. (Although in that specific case the argument is easier - all you need is that there is a Scott set not containing $0'$.)